# What is the difference between setlevel and addfilter in logging python

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn

I have recently started implementation logging in python. I have a hard time in understanding the difference between the setlevel and addfilter methods of logging. I feel they serve the same purpose. For ex, if we add logger.setlevel(debug) and logger.addfilter(logging.debug), they output same records. isn't?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects):

> The base filter class only allows events which are below a certain
>   point in the logger hierarchy. For example, a filter initialized with
>   ‘A.B’ will allow events logged by loggers ‘A.B’, ‘A.B.C’, ‘A.B.C.D’,
>   ‘A.B.D’ etc. but not ‘A.BB’, ‘B.A.B’ etc. If initialized with the
>   empty string, all events are passed.
>
> Note that filters attached to handlers are consulted before an event
>   is emitted by the handler, whereas filters attached to loggers are
>   consulted whenever an event is logged (using debug(), info(), etc.),
>   before sending an event to handlers. This means that events which have
>   been generated by descendant loggers will not be filtered by a
>   logger’s filter setting, unless the filter has also been applied to
>   those descendant loggers.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer myself. Filter is designed to let us add additional function-based filters on top of the level-based filtering that is done by default.

I found the answer from the link: https://realpython.com/python-logging-source-code/#the-filter-and-filterer-classes